# Auth window on wake

Tags: system

After my computer has been idle for a while and has gone into suspend, I get the following authorization window. When I type my password (I'm the only user on the machine), it won't accept it.

Anyone know what this is/why it happens?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1617687)
it happens to me as well as to many others
it doesn't however bother me much so I didn't even bother with a workaround